# Java, all instances of Person are linked to one object

Tags: java

I am currently writing a program but I found a problem. The problem is that in this loop below all instances of the class Person are attached to one instance of Item. What I want is that a Person each have his own Item. Do you have any suggestions?

Class simulate:

```
public void simulate(int days){

    for(int i=0;i<days;i++) {

        int persons = 10;

        for(int j=0;j<persons;j++){

            Person person = new Person();

            Item item = new Item();

            person.setItem(item);
        }
     }
 }
```

Class Person:

```
private Item item;

public void setItem(Item item)
{
        this.item = item;
}
```

Comment: You create a new `Object` each iteration, so each `Person` *does* have their own `Object`. `getObject()` should probably be called `setObject()`

Comment: `getObject()` for a setter is confusing.

Comment: `new Person;` should be `new Person();`. Same for `Object`. Rest seems to be fine, except that your `getObject` method should be `setObject`.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I get for coding in this editor. I hope the typo's are gone and we can continue with the problem.

Comment: Your latest version should work.

Comment: What is you exact error? How do you observe it? Print class instances with `System.identityHashCode()` to show they are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want is that a Person each have his own Item.

But that's exactly what you're doing. You're creating instances of `Person` and each newly created instance receives an newly created instance of `Item`

```
for(int j=0;j<persons;j++){
  Person person = new Person();
  Item item = new Item();
  person.setItem(item);
}
```

Only that you do not keep references to all those objects that have been created. So they'll be garbage collected sooner or later. Your loop is equivalent to

```
for(int j=0;j<persons;j++){
  new Person().setItem(new Item());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your `get` should be a `set`

For all the Person objects to be using the same object, you would have to have made your field `static`.  Don't do that, remove the `static` keyword from this field.  I suggest you not make your fields static unless they are constants (where possible)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is all kinds of wrong, and I'm sure it doesn't compile.

If you want to build a Person object with a parameter of type object being passed on the constructor, you need to do:

```
Object someKindOfObject = new Object(); //should really be a specific type...
Person person = new Person(sometKindOfObject);
```

A getSomething method should NEVER change the state of the object, just return information about it. If you don't want to use the constructor option, create a setObject method.

Answer (score 1):

Where you are storing the person objects?Each time you are over-writing the person object with new reference.So coming out of loop, you will be having a single object reference.Here is the corrected code which you are expecting i guess;-)

```
public void simulate(int days){

    for(int i=0;i<days;i++) {

        int persons = 10;

        Person[] personArray = new Person[persons];

        for(int j=0;j<persons;j++){

            personArray[j] = new Person();

            Object object = new Object();

            personArray[j].setObject(object);
        }

//here you have the reference to all person objects in array
     }
 }
```

class Person

```
public void setObject(Object object)
{
        this.object = object;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Now the code looks working or the problem is not evident. The OP should present more details about what error he/she receives.

Error in initial post was here:

```
public void getObject(Object Object)
{
        this.object = object;
}
```

you should name formal parameter `object` instead of `Object`, i.e. write

```
public void getObject(Object object)
```

instead of

```
public void getObject(Object Object)
```

Java is case sensitive.

Line `this.object = object;` does nothing in your code since assigning field `object` to itself. Separate variable `Object` plays no role. And you should get warning about it.

Also you'd better name method `setObject`.

Comment: `this.object = object;` is perfectly fine... assuming the rest of his code wasn't full of typos.

Comment: `this.object = object` assigns object to the a field of the current object referenced by `this`.

Comment: @Jon7 no you are wrong. `this.object=object` WOULD be fine if there were `object` local variable. But it is not.

Comment: @Hunter, you are wrong too. Look at the spelling of formal parameter carefully.

Comment: Keep in mind, that line is in a different class. A class that he hasn't given us. So we have no idea if there's a local variable.

Comment: The method code is complete here. We have local variable `Object` and a field `object`. They are unrelated.

Comment: `public void getObject(Object object)`
instead of
`public void getObject(Object Object)` looks same to me

Comment: @Dims I am assuming that was a typo when writing the code here, since `Object` is a class name you cannot create variables with that name in Java.

Comment: @Hunter you can make a variable named `Object`. Try it.

Comment: @Dims hmm I didn't think you could do that, my mistake. And obviously it was a typo, because the OP fixed it in his post 4 minutes ago, so *no* this is not a correct answer.

Comment: @Hunter then remove your minuses pls

Comment: @Hunter current code should work. I see no reasons assignment not work now. Probably OP has another problems not visible here.

Comment: @Dims Sorry I think I need to put glasses. Your point was quite right.

Comment: @Dimns I never run my horse in this race.